# can I use vanilla javascript in ionic3?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic3

so in my web app, I used something like this:

```
var id1 = '';

var imgPreview1 = document.getElementById('img-prev1');
var fileUpload1 = document.getElementById('file-input1');

fileUpload1.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
var file = event.target.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET);

axios({
    url: CLOUDINARY_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: formData
}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    imgPreview1.src = res.data.secure_url;
    id1 = res.data.secure_url;
    console.log(id1);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
});
```

in Ionic, can I use something like this? like bind this piece of javascript to an `<input type="file">`?